# CPU cooler size

Tags: cpu

I want to change my CPU cooler because it makes too much noise, I only don't know if this one fits and if it cools better.

The one I have: http://www.geeks.com/details.asp?invtid=E30307-001-R

The one I want: http://www.startech.com/Computer-Parts/Fans/Value-Socket-T775-Heatsink-with-Fan~FAN775E

Comment: There are "tower" heat pipe coolers (if you have the space) that cost little more than that, will use 120mm (or 140mm) fans. Due to the large passive area for heat removal and the larger fan pushing similar CFM with way less RPMs (the whiney noise), they would be both quiet and cooler. There are also a few that are not tall towers that still use similar designs of large radiators and large fans, if your limited in height spaces. What your have linked will be better than a stock similar, but some research could get you well beyond that.

Answer (score 1):

If it's the same socket and it is, socket 775 it will fit.
The cooler you currently have is noisier 32.2 ~ 41.1 dBA but I think it cools better because it moves up to 61.78 cubic feet of air per minute. The fan you want to buy has noise level <22.2 dBA and moves 49.37 CFM but it doesn't mean it will be cooling worse, that needs to be put on the test.